# CN1 CodeScanner not working

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I am having issues with the CodeScanner not returning values in my application.

This project I have had unchanged for a year and it was working, but there were some new changes that had to be done and when I was making them I noticed I was using a now deprecated scanner and I was to use the new library. I implemented it into the application and it loads correctly, but after I scan the QR code it never goes into the Completed method.

```
import com.codename1.ext.codescan.CodeScanner;
import com.codename1.ext.codescan.ScanResult;
...

if (CodeScanner.isSupported()) {
    CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {
        public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
            Dialog.show("Scanning Completed", "Scanning Completed", "OK", null);
        }

        public void scanCanceled() {
            Dialog.show("Scanning Cancelled", "Scanning was cancelled", "OK", null);
        }

        public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
            NoScanner(2);
        }
    });
} else {
    NoScanner(2);
}
```

I am hoping I can get some help as to why it suddenly doesn't want to return the scanned value or even enter the various methods.

This was tested on Android, there is also an iOS build but I don't have a device handy for testing

Comment: Is the syntax error in the `scanCompleted` method intentional? `Dialog.show("Scanning Completed", "Scanning Completed",` <- where's the rest of the code?

Comment: I was removing code for the Stackoverflow post that couldn't be displayed here and went overboard haha. But for one of my tests I had just the full dialog code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a regression in intent handling that we fixed over the weekend. Please try this again and see if the issue resolved itself.

Comment: I rebuilt the application first thing when coming in this morning and it solved the issue. Thank you :)